# HTTP Proxy with monitor UI for local install

Tags: http, testing, proxy

I'm looking for an HTTP Proxy/GUI combination that should be installed locally on my Windows PC. The UI should display something similar to Firebugs "Network" tab, showing request/response headers and content as plaintext.

It would be cool if I could attach requests to different 'nodes' for later comparison, similar to what you can do when using the Proxy that comes with JMeter.

Edit: I don't want something that only works with Firefox or only with IE. I want something independent, to use it with any browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few solutions for that, but one that integrates nicely with Firefox and works well for me is [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

It's free, and you can not only inspect traffic but also modify it, and a lot more :)